# T-SQL: Double-cocked Trigger, Polling or a .NET Async Thread?

Tags: linq-to-sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

So i bet i got you curious with that title. =)

Here's the scenario - simplified for the cause.

```
Website: ASP.NET 4 Web Forms.
Database: SQL Server 2008.
DAL: LINQ-SQL.
```

In the DB, we have two tables: `Foo` and `Bar`.

Relationship is `1-1`, and `Bar` has a foreign key constraint to `Foo`. In other words, you need to create `Foo` first, then use the PK for `Foo` when creating `Bar`. The two tables join to create a business entity called `FooBar`.

Now, we have a scoring system in place for our website. Certain actions cause the need for scoring to be refreshed for particular `FooBar`'s.

At the moment, we have triggers on both `Foo` and `Bar` tables. Both triggers calls a stored procedure which updates the scores for the particular `FooBar`.

So therein lies the problem - we create a new `FooBar` on the website, which causes entries in `Foo` and `Bar` to be created. Both triggers get fired (`Foo` first, then `Bar`), and the same stored procedure is executed twice. Doesnt do any actual harm, just not good for performance.

How can we get around this?

The stored procedure that updates the scores for `FooBar`'s is simple - takes in a `FooID`.

We cannot perform the scoring until after the entry in `Bar` is created. Even though it currently does happen for the `Foo` trigger, the score turns out to be incorrect until its redone on the `Bar` trigger. Also a thing to note is that doing something on the website may not affect BOTH tables (ie you can edit a `FooBar` on the website and only end up modifying the `Foo` table, or only the `Bar` table, other times both).

The triggers are `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE`.

Here's what i mean for three possible scenarios:

1. User creates a new FooBar:

   - New entry added to Foo
   - Trigger executed on Foo
   - Scoring SP Executed
   - FooBar scored incorrectly (because no Bar yet)
   - New entry added to Bar
   - Trigger executed on Bar
   - Scoring SP Executed
   - FooBar scored correctly
2. User edits the "Foo" for a FooBar:

   - Foo entry updated.
   - Trigger executed on Foo
   - Scoring SP Executed
   - FooBar scored correctly.
3. User edits the "Bar" for a FooBar:

   - Bar entry updated.
   - Trigger executed on Bar
   - Scoring SP Executed
   - FooBar scored correctly.

So scenarios 2 and 3 are fine - its when adding new FooBar's that causes the issue.

Here's my ideas so far:

1. Remove triggers from `Foo` and `Bar`. Create Asynchronous thread call in C# post-success creation of `Foo` and `Bar` table entries (ie after success of `LINQ` operations), calling stored procedure. Problem with this is firstly i always try to avoid threading in web sites unless absolutely required, furthermore its adding a dependency to the web server when in fact all of this logic and ownership should be (and currently is) on the database.
2. Create a "staging" table, the triggers would create an entry in the staging table (something like `"FooID1", "ReadyToScore"` - for example). Then a SQL Job would poll this table (say every 30 seconds) and execute the stored procedure. Obvious problems with this is extra load due to the polling, and more difficulty to debug.

Tough question to understand i know, so hopefully ive explained it ok.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to keep it as it is (doing processing twice).

Reasons:
 - The processing itself is quite efficient (< 1 sec). 
 - Polling, threading, Async T-SQL VS two 1 second calls. No brainer there.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider [Asynchronous T-SQL Procedures](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/), which eliminate the need for pooling job(s) and even for staging tables.

Comment: Interesting...never knew about that. I'll check it out - cheers for the tip!